# Make md-tooltip always active?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to make some tooltips to be always active, or to be able to activate them when my mouse goes close (not on top of the button) to the element.

Right now I have this setup:

```
<!-- BUTTONS SIDEBAR MENU -->
<div class="mini-sidebar-menu">
  <md-button aria-label="television" ng-click="television()" class="md-fab md-raised md-primary md-mini half">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="showTooltip" md-autohide="false">
      scroll to 1
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
  <md-button aria-label="mejor imagen" ng-click="mejorImagen()" class="md-fab md-raised md-primary md-mini half">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="showTooltip" md-autohide="false">
      scroll to 2
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
  <md-button aria-label="dvr" ng-click="dvr()" class="md-fab md-raised md-primary md-mini half">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="showTooltip" md-autohide="false">
      scroll to 3
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
  <md-button aria-label="ppv" ng-click="ppv()" class="md-fab md-raised md-primary md-mini half">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="showTooltip" md-autohide="false">
      <span class="md-body">scroll to 4</span>
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
  <md-button aria-label="paquetes" ng-click="paquetesTemporada()" class="md-fab md-raised md-primary md-mini half">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="showTooltip" md-autohide="false">
      scroll to 5
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
  <md-button aria-label="on demand" ng-click="onDemand()" class="md-fab md-raised md-primary md-mini half">
    <md-tooltip md-direction="left" md-visible="showTooltip" md-autohide="false">
      scroll to 6
    </md-tooltip>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

these are always on the right of the screen but they are just dots, I want to be able to show the tooltips when ever the mouse gets close, or I scroll down to a certain section of the page.

Right now I have this as the mouse event when it gets close to the right of the screen:

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$scope.showTooltip = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
  currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;

  if (currentMousePos.x > $(window).width() / 1.6) {
    $scope.showTooltip = true;
    console.log('mouse to the right: ' + currentMousePos);
    $('.mini-sidebar-menu').css({'opacity': '1'});
  } else {
    $scope.showTooltip = false;
    $('.mini-sidebar-menu').css({'opacity': '.1'});
  }
});
```

This makes the opacity go up, but at the same time I would like to display all of the tooltips when the mouse gets to this position.

Now each of them get an active class when I scroll down to a certain area like this:

```
// FUNCTION TO MAKE SIDE MENU BUTTON ACTIVE DEPENDING ON WHICH SECTION
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('body .section').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 85){
      $('.mini-sidebar-menu button.half').removeClass('active').addClass('md-mini');
      $('.mini-sidebar-menu button.half').eq(i).addClass('active').removeClass('md-mini');
    };
  });
});
```

and at the same time it would be nice to show the tooltip for that specific button when they reach that section of the page.

**QUESTIONS**

- How to show all tooltips of the sidebar buttons when the mouse gets close to them (not on hover, just close).
- How to make a tooltip appear when I scroll down to a certain section that belongs to that sidebar button.

**RESEARCH**

I've read the documentation at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTooltip and tried messing around with the options but with no success.

Comment: Hey, ddi you et this to work? I'm getting this error if I try to use the double negation workaround: Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '!(!item.showTooltip)' used with directive 'mdTooltip' is non-assignable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make them always active, then apparently two-way data binding stops working if you make the expression used in `md-visible` more complicated than just a reference to a field.

Double-negating `md-visible="!(!showTooltip)"` should do the trick in most cases.

Comment: I had the same issue and tried your solution but I'm getting the following error:

Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '!(!item.showTooltip)' used with directive 'mdTooltip' is non-assignable!

Any ideas about what might be wrong?

Comment: It does throw that error, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. It simply fails to assign a new value to the specified variable, which keeps the value still.
There don't seem to be any better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah you're right but also not particularly keen on the idea of putting a component that throws an error on live. Is there any way to suppress these errors by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Was anyone able to avoid these errors [$compile:nonassign]?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ng-if="boolean_value"` before `md-visible="angural_propertie"`. This allows component binding once.

Comment: Works. Thanks. Why does this happen ?